# Using Kafka Streams Processor API to Combine Multiple Processors

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have 3 processors A, B and C. A and B are the sources for C. C writes to a topic and updates a state store.

```
public class A implements Processor<String,VIn,String,Void> {
  // get state stores

  private void punctuate(long timestamp) {
    if (condition) {
      // trigger Processor C
      processorContext.forward(..);
}

public class B implements Processor<String,VIn,String,Void> {
  // get state stores

  private void punctuate(long timestamp) {
    if (condition) {
      // trigger Processor C
      processorContext.forward(..);
}

public class C implements Processor<String,Void,String,VOut> {
  // get state stores

  @Override
  private void process(Record<String,Void> record) {
    // some logic involving states
    if (called by Processor B) {
      // save state in state store
    }
  }
}
```

Using a service for this logic seems messy because all processors talk to at least 2 state stores. There's also no real data flow between A->C and B->C--I want to trigger some logic based on punctuate(). I also tried Streams DSL but I can't make Processor C talk to both A and B (A and B would be Transformers). My question is this:

1. How do I update the state in Processor C based on whether Processor B triggered the flow?
2. Is this a viable design?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a header every time punctuate is called in Processor A and B. This header can be used to segregate data in Processor C.

```
public class A implements Processor<String,VIn,String,Void> {
  // get state stores

  // Processor A Header
  byte [] processorAHeader = "ProcessorA".getBytes(); 

  private void punctuate(long timestamp) {
    // Set the header for ProcessorA
    processorContext.headers().add("source", processorAHeader);
    
    if (condition) {
      // trigger Processor C
      processorContext.forward(..);
}

public class B implements Processor<String,VIn,String,Void> {
  // get state stores

  // Processor B Header
  byte [] processorBHeader = "ProcessorB".getBytes(); 

  private void punctuate(long timestamp) {
    // Set the header for ProcessorB
    processorContext.headers().add("source", processorBHeader);

    if (condition) {
      // trigger Processor C
      processorContext.forward(..);
}

public class C implements Processor<String,Void,String,VOut> {
  // get state stores

  @Override
  private void process(Record<String,Void> record) {

    // Extract the header from the record
    String source = new String(processorContext.headers().lastHeader("source").value());

    // some logic involving states
    if (source.equals("ProcessorB")) {
      // Processor B logic comes here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. We have decided to go with an alternate design but this is still useful information.